# Do I Need a License for an Electric Bike?

Tags: road-bike

Do I Need a License for an Electric Bike? Are There Age Restrictions for E-Bike Riders in New York city

Comment: Your question would greatly benefit from more details, particularly the country and the type of bike you are asking about.

Comment: I just googled _new york ebike license_ and got this: https://www.nyc.gov/html/dot/html/bicyclists/ebikes.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Germany

In Germany, e-bikes ('pedelecs') are license-free and not age restricted so long as they have a rated power of no more than 250W (although there is no limit to the max power output), and as long as the motor only assists up to 25 km/h, and as long as the motor only engages while you are pedaling.
for faster or more powerful bikes you need an insurance and a license for light motorcycles.

These rules only apply for usage of these bikes on public roads. On private property they do not apply.

Comment: Sorry, I am in New York City.

Answer (score 1):

E-bikes with the assisted speed 25 km/h usually do not require the license in most of the countries, while it may be requirements like minimum age, wear the helmet, lights also during the day and the like. You can check [specifically here](https://www.heybike.com/blogs/heybike-blog/new-york-ebike-laws?gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiApuCrBhAuEiwA8VJ6JpPwLRo0jwqtJn3S-p3of8scsD-2QAsoOEkAEl80zrZndVzaOYx8yxoCkuEQAvD_BwE) for New York City. They seem having more relaxed speed limits (20 miles/h that is about 32 km/h) and permit additional classes 2 and 3 (these as not E-bikes in many European countries).

"Fast" E-bikes that can assist above this speed (usually 45 km/h) require the driving license and bear license plates. These plates are the easiest way to tell the two kinds apart.

Above these maximal velocities, the controller turns off the engine of E-bike, leaving it with human power only. But most of the models are heavy, with wide knobby tires, hence speeding past the limits on human power alone is unusual.

Comment: Many countries (especially European and also Australia and New Zealand) have a maximum allowed motor power as well as a restricting assist below a speed   (varies from around 25-32km/h). Some enforce these rules more than others.